# Reading BGR values of pixel in OpenCV

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, numpy-ndarray, color-detection

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fL5Uk.png)I want to detect color of shape in an image, so when I am run the code
"bgr_list = img[cX,cY]"
I get this error:

```
bgr_list = img[cX,cY]                 
IndexError: index 648 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 598
        
        
but when I run "bgr_list = img[300,300]" I do not get any error  
->where [300,300] is white portion in image  
-> where, cX = x-coordinate of centroid and cY = y-coordinate of centroid  
-> BGR_list is bgr value of pixel at centroid  
-> the size of image is 898x598 pixel
```

Comment: just a guess: try changing the indexing line to `bgr_list = img[cY,cX]`

Comment: Thanks @DominikFicek it worked, can you also tell the logic behind reversing coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you get X and Y cartesian coordinates from some sort of preprocessing but `numpy` matrices which opencv uses, use matrix indexing `(row, column, channel)`. Your X coordinate corresponds with column index and Y coordinate is your row index.

Fliping the indices should do the work
`bgr_list = img[cY,cX]`